# Crypto and forex...here’s the scenario..need to know I can’t gelegally

Tags: foreign-exchange, cryptocurrency

Some says to you... ”Ok cool ...I’m a Bitcoin Investor lincense by SFOX .. I make my money off crypto investment and ForexTrading.. I Work online in the Social market. all I do is move commission profit From my wallet into your account by adding your personal online account while logged from outside the account after the deposit has been verified & posted for withdrawal you keep 30%each day and send back 70%(invest back 30% and keep 40% for myself)We can do this for the next 5-6 days as long as your are 100% trustworthy” is this legal and should I take a chance..?

Comment: "adding your personal online account" Your personal online bank account or your  Bitcoin exchange account? Either way, they're promising you money for nothing. That always ends badly. Steer well clear.

Comment: Everytime someone is offering you money for nothing, it is a scam.

Comment: Sounds like money laundering at best.

Answer (score 7):

No, you should not take a chance. This is a scam. See many other questions here tagged “scam” and “bitcoin” for details.

Answer (score 3):

In these scenarios, you have to ask Why? to gain some understanding.

I've made money from bitcoin, and cashed this money out.   What legitimate reason would I have to link someone else's account, cash out to their account and then let them keep 30%?

The only reasons are bad ones, e.g. Money Laundering, tax evasion, rip you off etc.

Don't go anywhere near this scenario, it is a scam.